# Installing AWS EFS CSI Operator using CLI

Tags: openshift

I have installed the AWS EFS CSI Driver operator following this guide [https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/storage/container_storage_interface/persistent-storage-csi-aws-efs.html#persistent-storage-csi-olm-operator-install_persistent-storage-csi-aws-efs][1]
and it works fine.

Now I have to install it using CLI (not the web console). I have tried using ./oc apply -f efs-susbscription.yaml. This is the efs subscription content.

```
 apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  name: aws-efs-csi-driver-operator  
  namespace: openshift-cluster-csi-drivers
spec:
  
  installPlanApproval: Automatic
  name: aws-efs-csi-driver-operator
  namespace: openshift-cluster-csi-drivers
  source: redhat-operators
  sourceNamespace: openshift-marketplace
```

It seems to install an operator, but I can't connect to my EFS filesystem. Also, in the operator hub of the web console, it appears as not installed.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Does your namespace has a OperatorGroup resource?

Comment: No, it hasn't. I need one? Can't you show me the needed yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing a Operator in a namespace other than openshift-operators, you need to create OperatorGroup resource in the namespace.

Here is a just example.

```
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1
kind: OperatorGroup
metadata:
  name: aws-efs-csi-driver-operator
  namespace: openshift-cluster-csi-drivers
spec:
  targetNamespaces:
 - openshift-cluster-csi-drivers
```

Here is the document how to install Operator from OperatorHub using the CLI.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/operators/user/olm-installing-operators-in-namespace.html#olm-installing-operator-from-operatorhub-using-cli_olm-installing-operators-in-namespace

Comment: That's absolutly right. In this case, the operator group shuld not have targetNamespaces or it does not work. Thanks!!